# Is it wrong to validate uniqueness with CanCanCan?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, access-control, cancancan

I want to ensure that a user cannot comment on a post twice. I can do this with model validations or CanCan. I think it would be nice to do it using CanCan because then I could do something like the following:

```
- if can?(:create, Comment)
  = render 'comments/form'
```

However then in my ability.rb I'd have something like this, which feels weird:

```
can :create, Comment do |comment|
  comment.user_id == user.id && !user.comments.exist?(post_id: comment.post_id)
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Although this might be possible to achieve using cancancan as well, you're better off using model validations to do the same for multiple reasons.

- By using the latter, you're separating your authorization logic from database-validation logic.
- Let's say you end up having a different role (other than `user`) in the future, the new role won't have the same restriction on posting comments. You would have to write the logic in ability.rb again which goes against the DRY principle.
- When a user tries to create a second comment, they'll be given a `403` error as opposed to a `400` which would be expected in this case.
- With the proper abstraction of these validation-checks, your unit tests will also be organized in a more sensible manner.